# New York Sales Tax Help

Tags: tax, sales

I'm having a hard time calculating tax.

I need to have it charge New York Sales Tax anytime the BILLING address is a New York address. But it either charges tax on all orders, even when the billing address is out of state, or it doesn't charge tax at all.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not the exact answer you are looking for but New York retail sales tax is destination based, not origin. Orders sent outside of the state are exempt from retail sales tax.

http://www.tax.ny.gov/bus/st/sales_tax_rates.htm

Comment: yeah but it's not charging the tax corrently in magento. Either it charges tax on all orders or it doesn't charge tax on new york sales, which it is supposed to.

Comment: Can you export your current tax rates and throw them in dropbox or such so we can review. Also what version of Magento are you currently working on?